# Can't see user's name on CloudKit Dashboard

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have a CloudKit app in the development environment with only one user (me).

I know that I have successfully made myself discoverable to the app as I can see my first name and family name from within the app.

But when I look at the CloudKit dashboard my 'User Record' shows up as 'No Name'.

I want to be able to see discoverable user's names on the dashboard so that I can allocate roles to them.

Any thoughts as to why I cannot see myself as 'discoverable' on the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

CloudKit Dashboard doesn't currently support showing the discoverable user name. Please file a Radar to Apple with an enhancement request.

The "No name" you are referring to is simply the value if no field name for the record type (in this case "Users") can be found that is suitable as the display value for each row (such as "name" or "title").

Comment: it used to support this as it was demonstrated in WWDC 2024, Session 231: "If we go to the user records, we can see everyone who's used this app so far. If they have marked themselves as discoverable, you're going to be able to see their first and last name. If they haven't, you're just going to see that recordID up there.". If you cannot see a discoverable user's name how do you know which user's to allocate security roles too?